# Simplifying a long complex regex

Tags: java, regex, simplify

I suck at creating regex each time i have to check an input.

I have to check that inputs have the correct format. Input format could be :

1. `AA:BB:CC DDD/EEE`
2. `CC DDD/EEE`

Don't mind the uppercase. A,B,C and D can be either a letter (in uppercase or not) or a digit.

I came up with this regex (which works) but how it can be simplified or even optimized.

```
([a-zA-Z0-9])*([:])?([a-zA-Z0-9])*([:])?([a-zA-Z0-9])+([ ]){1}([a-zA-Z0-9])+([/]){1}([a-zA-Z0-9])+
```

Comment: You could write `[:]` as `:`, write `[/]` as `/` and omit every `{1}`. If you are not using the capture groups later on, you can also omit those so `([:])?` would become `:?` The pattern could look like `\b(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+:[a-zA-Z0-9]+:[a-zA-Z0-9]+ )?[a-zA-Z0-9]+/[a-zA-Z0-9]+\b` making the first part optional to match `DDD/EEE` https://regex101.com/r/fq0FFa/1

Comment: Adding `(?i)` to the start of your regex would allow you to use simply `a-z` instead of `a-zA-Z`. Use `\d` instead of `0-9`

Comment: I corrected the second case. It was a bad copy/paste

Comment: Is `AA:BB DDD` valid?

Comment: No. It is not valid

Comment: What about `CC DDD/EEE/FFF`?

Comment: Is `AAA:BBB DDD/EE` valid?

Comment: Or what about `A:B D/E`?

Comment: Is there a maximum number of allowed colons or slashes?

Comment: Your sample data is very underwhelming and you provide no ruleset. Your current regex is very loose and will easily match too much. That's why I am asking 50 questions.

Comment: Simply put. It should accept only the formats specified in the question

Comment: The input format i provided are the expected format and not sample data.

Comment: I think the question is clear enough. The question was "how to shorten this regex?" right? It's not about what strings it should match. It's about coming up with a shorter regex that matches exactly the same things as the one provided. Voted the reopen.

Comment: I voted for closing it because of the long discussion in comments. Thanks all for your contribution.

Comment: If you don't mind matching underscore(_) character, then you can use \w instead of [a-zA-Z0-9]

Comment: @Sweeper I am personally not a fan of letting someone run head first through a curtain with a wall of knives hidden behind it. Knowing what OP is trying to achieve is integral to achieving it optimally. If the details don't matter then the question could have been reduced to OP's final sentence and the regex code.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus "Use `\d` instead of `0-9`" - keep in mind that `\d` matches more than just our Roman digits so it's not an exact replacement although this might not be a problem here (e.g. if an encoding that only supports Roman digits would be used :) ).

Comment: Are you referring to Java's regex implementation? The [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#predef) state that `\d` is equivalent to `[0-9]`. Correct me if I am mistaken.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus you're right I probably mixed that up with either another implementation or a different notation.

Comment: @Thomas Looks like Python 2 has some special rules based on the `/u` flag. "When the UNICODE flag is not specified, matches any decimal digit; this is equivalent to the set `[0-9]`. With UNICODE, it will match whatever is classified as a decimal digit in the Unicode character properties database." Python 3 seems to be slightly different as well. I have no idea if this is applicable to Java as their docs don't seem to specify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you only put one character in the `[]`s, then the `[]`s are redundant, so `[/]` can be simplified to `/`, `[:]` can be simplified to `:` etc.
- You also don't need to specify that something repeats `{1}` time, so those can be removed.
- `0-9` inside the `[]`s can be simplified to `\d`:

Applying the above, we get:

```
([a-zA-Z\d])*(:)?([a-zA-Z\d])*(:)?([a-zA-Z\d])+( )([a-zA-Z\d])+(/)([a-zA-Z\d])+
```

- `(:)?` will either capture `:` or nothing (`null`). If you don't need this, you can remove the group. Similarly `( )` will always capture a space, which seems quite pointless.
- `([a-zA-Z\d])*` will only capture the last repeat. You might want `([a-zA-Z\d]*)` , or not to capture anything.

Assuming you don't want to capture anything, hence removing all the groups, we get:

```
[a-zA-Z\d]*:?[a-zA-Z\d]*:?[a-zA-Z\d]+ [a-zA-Z\d]+/[a-zA-Z\d]+
```

Last but not least:

- At the start, `[a-zA-Z\d]*:?` is repeated twice, we can use a `{2}` quantifier.
- If you pass the `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` option to `Pattern.compile`, you don't need to specify `A-Z` every time.

Now we get:

```
([a-z\d]*:?){2}[a-z\d]+ [a-z\d]+/[a-z\d]+
```